# Change value of an input

Tags: jquery, html

Okay, I have this code

```
<input id=a value=test />
<textarea id=b></textarea>
<script>
$(function () {
var value = $('input#a').val();
$('textarea#b').val(value);
});
</script>
```

So the question is how to change to value of the textarea when someone changes the value of the input ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<input id="txt" value="" />
<textarea id="txtA"></textarea>​
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){
    $('#txt').on('keyup', function(e){
        $('#txtA').val($(this).val());
    });
});​
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/5pnRn/)

Comment: I'm sorry, it's not what I am asking.

Comment: Then what is that, can you tell me more ?

Comment: Actually, that is what you're asking. Try to rephrase your question so every of us can understand.

Comment: Okay, so the current value of the input is "test" and when the user change the value of that input, the value of the textarea doesnt change, it's still "test". Ex: http://jsfiddle.net/creepyzero/5pnRn/2/, there is no value in the textarea.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand what do you exactly want.

Comment: Do you want to change the value of the text area when the value of the input is not test ?

Comment: Or http://jsfiddle.net/heera/5pnRn/4/, this will change the value of the textarea only when the value of the input not begins with 123.

Comment: No sir, take a look at this one http://jsfiddle.net/creepyzero/5pnRn/5/, if you change the input value, the textarea value won't change. Your code in the first post doesn't have input value.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#a').change(function() { $('#b').val($(this).val()); });
```

(edit: id selector instead of tag selector)

Comment: This will not work if there are other input or textareas on the screen.